# Swift 4 Xcode 9 UISlider 3 colors visible from the start

Tags: xcode, colors, swift4, uislider

How can i make a slider 3 colors Yellow, Green, Red in swift 4 Xcode 9? They should be in that order and if you start the app you shall see it as a 3 colored slider. no tintcolored slider that changes colors after where the thumb is. it shall be three colored eaven if it has not been interacted with. The slider thumb shall change color after the slider color.

[image: Description picture]

Comment: Show your code, what have you tried so far? This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: i have tried minimumTint and maximumTint i have tried to find a value inside the slider that the thumb isn't on i don't know what eaven to try cuz the slider is setup with two colors from the start and what i understand there is no way to change that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used CAGradientLayer for designing the max and min track images of the slider and a rectangle for the slider thumb image. Feel free to customize it to your needs

```
 func setSlider(slider:UISlider) {
    let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: slider.bounds.width, height: 20.0 )
    tgl.frame = frame

    tgl.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

    tgl.borderWidth = 1.0
    tgl.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    tgl.cornerRadius = 5.0

    tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:  1.0)
    tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:  1.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    slider.setMaximumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)
    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)

    let layerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10.0, height: 30.0)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = CGPath(rect: layerFrame, transform: nil)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    let thumb = CALayer.init()
    thumb.frame = layerFrame
    thumb.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(thumb.frame.size, false, 0.0)

    thumb.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let thumbImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    slider.setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
    slider.setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .highlighted)
}
```

[image]

Comment: first i wanna say thanks i have had alot of trouble with this thing that seems like a very simple thing but really isn't. But now i wonder is the func setSlider(slider: UISlider) is the parameter name meant to be sender or am i fully wrong?^^thanks once again

Comment: Just add a UISlider layout in storyboard and link it to your view controller, then in your viewDidLoad pass the slider to the function.

Comment: i get a red little extra slider at the end is that any problem that you encountered?